# How do I tell if a given Android phone is vulnerable to CVE-2012-4221, CVE-2013-2596, CVE-2013-2597, CVE-2013-6282?

Tags: security

I want to determine if a given Android Phone + OS is vulnerable to a set of CVEs.

What process do I need to do to do to determine if a given Phone is vulnerable?

Comment: You can use one of the many apps for [Exploit Protection](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_antimalware#group_447) (and detection). But what CVEs they cover, is a different question.

Answer (score 1):

CVE-2012-4221 has a [patch](https://www.codeaurora.org/projects/security-advisories/multiple-issues-diagkgsl-system-call-handling-cve-2012-4220-cve-2012), which you could examine to determine how to exploit the unpatched code — and then write code to exploit it, and run it on your phone.  You could probably do this with many such issues.

You are not likely to find any kind of complete suite ready-made for this kind of testing, since it would just be making things easier for those with malicious intentions.